# Numpy: map a list of arrays to an array of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to map a list of numpy arrays (containing a single string) to an array of arrays. I want this because I need it to be in that specific format to save it to a .mat file.

I currently have the following:

```
var1 = [array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'), array(['String2'], dtype='<U9'), ...]
var2 = np.asarray(var1)

output when printing var2: 
[['String1']
 ['String2']
 ['String3']
 ...]
```

It seems like it is creating a list of lists instead of an array of arrays of some sort. Might it be that `.asarray` simply can't handle 2D arrays and I need another function? Or am I making a simple mistake here.

```
Expected output:
array([[array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'),
        array(['String2'], dtype='<U9'),
        array(['String3'], dtype='<U9'),
        ...]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: add expected output

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: You don't see that `array(...)` because you printed it out and python decided to just show you the data within it. but if you do `type(var2)`, it is an numpy array. Or if you just type `var2` in your python prompt, you see what you want to see. Each of the element inside your `var2` is also array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var2` *is* a NumPy array, but when you print a NumPy array it just happens to show something similar to a list, although if you print a nested list with that content you will see that it is not printed in that vertical format.

The reason why printing `var1` shows `array(...)` around each array in the list is because `var1` is a `list`, not a NumPy array. When you print a `list`, you see the string [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)esentation of the object, which does not necessarily match how the object is shown on printing. If you do `print(repr(var2))` you will see the `array(...)` around it.

In any case, you can always use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) to check what type is your object.

Answer (score 0):

You start with a list of arrays:

```
In [49]: var1 = [np.array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'), np.array(['String2'], dtype='<U9')]               
In [50]: var1                                                                                          
Out[50]: [array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'), array(['String2'], dtype='<U9')]
```

Making an array from that - 2d array with a string dtype (default `np.array` behavior):

```
In [51]: var2 = np.array(var1)                                                                         
In [52]: var2                                                                                          
Out[52]: 
array([['String1'],
       ['String2']], dtype='<U9')      # (2,1) shape
```

specifying object dtype still produces a (2,1) array

```
In [53]: var3 = np.array(var1, object)                                                                 
In [54]: var3                                                                                          
Out[54]: 
array([['String1'],
       ['String2']], dtype=object)      # the objects are python strings
```

To create an array of arrays, you have to first create an 'blank' array, and then fill it:

```
In [55]: var3 = np.empty(2, object)                                                                    
In [56]: var3                                                                                          
Out[56]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
In [57]: var3[:] = var1                                                                                
In [58]: var3                                                                                          
Out[58]: 
array([array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'), array(['String2'], dtype='<U9')],
      dtype=object)
```

If the list contained arrays of differing length you could use `np.array`, but as shown, that's not a robust construct (but common, if only by mistake):

```
In [61]: np.array([np.array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'), np.array(['String2', 'string3'], dtype='<U9')]) 
Out[61]: 
array([array(['String1'], dtype='<U9'),
       array(['String2', 'string3'], dtype='<U9')], dtype=object)
```

A `numpy` array of arrays is an odd bird, and requires a more convoluted construction.